# Pause on any error/exception and pause on submit

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I need a little orientation regarding Google Chrome debugger. 
My application works only in Google Chrome because of well HTML5 support.

How can you pause on every single error/exception detected?

The source of this question it's the fact I'm doing a simple form submit with some Javascript validations. 
On clicking the submit button I can see an error appearing in my Dev Tools Errors  Frame, but it switch immediately to my PHP called on submit still in development, switching the page and therefore I can't read the error.

I've tried setting breakpoints and I've clicked on that pause on exceptions button, but it's not helping me, I'm doing something wrong. 
I do not know completely how to use the debugger.

Comment: possible duplicate?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors

Comment: I read that question and others before posting, however my question also asks about pausing just before it changes page when submitting. I didn't find an answer to this, just some questions with Firefox extensions as answers, but I need a way to do it with Google Chrome. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered trying to put a break point in a handler function for the window.onSubmit event?

Maybe something like this for jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/7UZsk/27/

```
$(window).bind('submit',function(){
  alert("submitting");
});​
```

This is the actual DOM event reference:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onsubmit

Comment: I'm not so sure how to do it... you mean using JQuery? u.u

Comment: I did it now. Your suggestion it's helpful indeed, but this is an action triggered at the moment of submit, quite handy yeah, thanks. But there must be a way to pause with Chrome's debugger, isn't it??
I'll accept this as an answer because it has solved my problem (sorry for the delay, I have many things to do at work). I wish someone can post a way to do it with Chrome's Debugger and I'll set that answer as the real answer. Meanwhile: THANKS A LOT =)