# Modal error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Im using the following code and I got error in delete in the `JS($("#deleteModal").modal("show");`),any idea what can be wrong here ?
Im using MVC5 project

the error is

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Delete Item</h4>
            </div>
            <div id="deleteModalBody" class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");  // initially hides the modal pop-up until needed

        $(".deleteLink").on("click", function () {

            $.get('@Url.Action("GetDeletePartial")', { id: $(this).prop("id") }, function (data) {
                $("#deleteModalBody").html(data);

                $("#deleteModal").modal("show");  // shows the modal pop-up now that we have our partial view
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

when I try it like following it fail in the begging of the script with the same error

```
@section scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>   

    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");  // initially hides the modal pop-up until needed

            $(".deleteLink").on("click", function () {

                $.get('@Url.Action("GetDeletePartial")', { id: $(this).prop("id") }, function (data) {
                    $("#deleteModalBody").html(data);

                    $("#deleteModal").modal("show");  // shows the modal pop-up now that we have our partial view
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are attempting to make a model dialog using some third-party jQuery plugin, but you foget to make a reference to that plugin's javascript file.

To confirm this, i wonder which line does the exception occurs on? Is it on the line of first line of your ready callback?

> $("#deleteModal").modal("hide");

If so, please check your script reference. Just add a <script> tag with a src to that file before your script block.

Update:

As you comments, the exception does not occurs on that line. So you may use a debugger(such as Chrome developer tools) to find out which function-call fails. You can set the debugger to pause the excution on exceptions.
In chrome developer tools, you can switch to Source tab and click the last icon on right-top of the side-bar on the right to enable this feature. Here's an awesome answer with snapshots: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17324511/1817042

Comment: Thanks chan but not its happen in  $("#deleteModal").modal("show");,there is a way which I can see in the the debugger what is the reason for it ,like more detailes ?

Comment: Yes, the developer tools in chrome provide a good way: the debugger can break the running process on exceptions. Press F12 to launch the developer tools, switch to Source tab, and on the right-top of the sidebar, the last icon sets the behaviour for wheather to break on exceptions. You can then dig in and find out which function-call fails.

Comment: Where in the right top of the side bar,does this icon have a name?please see my updated post...

Comment: Please see my updated post,do you know which referance I should put explicit maybe for bootstrap ?

Comment: Yes I believe you've missed a script reference which provide the modal functionality. P.S. I added a link to snapshots for pause on exceptions in Chrome developer tools.

Comment: So if you are using Bootstrap, do you include bootstrap.min.js in your page before this script block?

Comment: yes and when I include it I have error in the delete at the end of the script,im getting the same error...:(

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error on standalone plain old HTML+Javascript page.

Apparently caused by socket.io.js which script tag was initially placed after jquery and bootstrap.js script tags.

Moving socket.io.js script tag before jquery and bootstrap resolved the issue for me.