# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

Hi I am trying to load bootstrap modal on page load.

I have referred this links:

[Modal error - Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978937/modal-error-uncaught-typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-modal)

[Bootstrap : TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32326074/bootstrap-typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function)

[TypeError: $(…).modal is not a function with bootstrap Modal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064176/typeerror-modal-is-not-a-function-with-bootstrap-modal)

So As per them I arranged my scripts as:

```
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script>      
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/scripts.js');?>"></script>
```

And My Modal code like this:

```
<div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Subscribe our Newsletter</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Subscribe to our mailing list to get the latest updates straight in your inbox.</p>
                <form>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address">
                    </div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Subscribe</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
</script>
```

But I am still getting the error on my modal is not being loaded. What can be the possible solution to this? How should be my scripts called in correct way

[image: error]

[image: Console error]

Comment: Make sure you have included the jquery ui library.

Comment: @Aditya i have included  but still its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you import bootstrap.min.js correctly you don't need jquery-ui.

In this [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/rixlabs/7fs1wgzy/) you can found a functionin version of your modal with only bootsrap dependencies

Comment: after i removed all the scripts except the ajax and boostrap.min.js the error was gone and my screen also faded but i cant see the modal yet

Comment: Remove the hide form the class <div class="modal hide fade" id="myModal"> ;)

Comment: when i try to see the link, throw 404 not found

Answer (score 2):

Note that although you include jQuery and jQueryUI, you then add another two versions of jQuery *after* jQueryUI (4 in total) which then supercedes the jQueryUI methods. You only need a single reference to jQuery, so remove those extra ones. Try this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="<?php echo site_url('js/bootstrap.min.js'); ?>"></script> 
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/jquery.backstretch.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/retina-1.1.0.min.js');?>"></script>
<script src="<?php echo site_url('assets/js/scripts.js');?>"></script>
```

Also note that both jQueryUI and Bootstrap have methods named `modal()` and could be conflicting with each other. I would strongly recommend you use only one of those libraries. Personally I would suggest Bootstrap over jQueryUI.

Comment: I tried this but I am still getting that error @rory

Comment: i have added an screen shot where the console shows error

Comment: Is the script being loaded correctly? Are there any other errors above the one you've shown in the console?

Comment: You should look at fixing those other errors first as they could be stopping script execution before jQueryUI can be loaded.

Comment: i removed those from my code but still the same error and i was loading those scripts at last so maybe they were not causing problem

Comment: after i removed all the scripts except the ajax and boostrap.min.js the error was gone and my screen also faded but i cant see the modal yet

Comment: That's because you have the `hide` class on it.