# How to turn on Pause On Uncaught Exceptions in Google Chrome Canary?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, gwt, script-debugging

In this article it talks about turning on pausing on uncaught exceptions.
 https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging

I can only see Pause On Caught Exceptions in both Chrome and Canary. I'm using Chrome Canary Version 43.0.2344.2 canary (64-bit).

[image]

I'm getting a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :, sourcing to a location (e.g. VM272) and it's very difficult to track down without a trace of the call stack.

[image]

I've searched and found that I can add

```
> window.onerror = function() { debugger;}
```

In the console, but that doesn't get me a stack trace. The Scope window does provide a lot of variable info, but I'm still a bit lost.

[image]

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docuemntation is a little bit outdated.

In the new Chrome versions the "pause on exception" button doesn't toggle anymore between 3 states (**disabled**, "**Pause on Exceptions**","**Pause on Uncaught Exceptions**") but only between two states (**disabled** and "**Pause on Exception**").

In order to be able to also break on **caught exceptions** they introduced this checkbox (this is useful if you have a global exception handler in `GWT` but still want to break when the exception is thrown).

So if you don't catch the exception then the settings you have shown in your screenshot should work.

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks. But why wouldn't the error, Uncaught SyntaxError, force a pause?

Comment: It should. Does it break when you check the "pause on caught exceptions" ?

Comment: No it doesn't. (That would have been too easy.) I should create a new question on how to debug this error.

Comment: I have the same problem as OP. this explanation points out what should happen, not what actually does happen (i.e. that uncaught errors do not (just-in-time-style) stop the debugger).

Comment: I can confirm, that my debugger does not stop on what seems like Uncaught Exceptions. =(