# How do you debug React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, debugging

How does one debug their React code with React Native while the app is running in app simulator?

Comment: Apart from these answers, if you're working on VS Code and want to debug in it rather than Chrome, then [check my this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56233781/1055241)

Comment: Please follow this blog.
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/react-native-debug-with-vscode-in-simple-steps-bf39b6331e67

Answer (score 189):

Mac: <kbd>Cmd+M</kbd>

Windows and Linux: <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd>

Use the appropriate hotkey above from within the Simulator. It'll popup Chrome and from there you can use the Developer Tools.

[image]

Edit:

This is now linked in the [help docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content).

Comment: Using v8.2 simulator, Cmd+D seems to do nothing. Chrome is latest. Is some special plugin in chrome needed or a proxy?

Comment: Getting "Websocket debugger is not available. Did you forget to include RCTWebSocketExecutor?". :/

Comment: **From within the Simulator** is the important bit.

Comment: I had the following error: /Users/Serge/projects/serge/MyProject/node_modules/react-native/packager/launchChromeDevTools.applescript:668:671: script error: Expected class name but found property. (-2741). I found out that if I disabled sharing Windows applications with Mac in Parallels that it starts working. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29310936/how-to-disable-start-of-parallels-when-script-interacts-with-google-chrome.

Comment: @AndréStaltz it also works from real devices. I added a note in the doc how to get it working http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content

Comment: @TylerMcGinnis facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content

Comment: note if you're integrating with cocoapods, make sure you have `pod 'React/RCTWebSocketDebugger'`

Comment: What's this `Cmd` stuff? I'm on Windows.

Comment: @WayneBloss Or `CTRL+M` for developer menu in windows

Comment: That'll be `Cmd+M` on OS X and Android

Comment: I had the same problem as McG - use CMD + D and let the browser launch from the Debug JS remotely option. Mine took awhile to launch but eventually started working

Comment: Note you may have to look in a strange place in the "sources" tab to find your code. For me it was under `debuggerWorker.js->172.29.208.1:19001->node_modules/expo`

Comment: Note that Cmd+D will do nothing if your Build Configuration is set to "Release"- make sure it is set to "Debug".

Answer (score 101):

### Debugging React Native Apps

To debug the javascript code of your react app do the following:

1. Run your application in the iOS simulator.
2. Press `Command + D` and a webpage should open up at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui. (Chrome only for now) or use the `Shake Gesture`
3. Enable [Pause On Caught Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors/17324511#17324511) for a better debugging experience.
4. Press `Command + Option + I` to open the Chrome Developer tools, or open it via `View` -> `Developer` -> `Developer Tools`.
5. You should now be able to debug as you normally would.

#### Optional

Install the [React Developer Tools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en) extension for Google Chrome. This will allow you to navigate the view hierarchy if you select the `React` tab when the developer tools are open.

### Live Reload

To activate Live Reload do the following:

1. Run your application in the iOS simulator.
2. Press `Control + Command + Z`.
3. You will now see the `Enable/Disable Live Reload`, `Reload` and `Enable/Disable Debugging` options.

Comment: This answer basically copies the doc, which is a start, but not especially illuminating.  What does "debug as you normally would" mean in this context?

Comment: Important note: React Developer Tools hasn't been working with React Native for months, and remains to be fixed. More info here: https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/229

Comment: Who said this is on mac?

Comment: @shinzou it's implied by the mention of a simulator (it's simulator for iOS devs, emulator for Android devs). Yes I know it's been a while, but still, just FWIW

Comment: that extension doesn't work with react-native. instead, you should see this: https://reactnative.dev/docs/debugging#react-developer-tools

Answer (score 74):

For an Android App, if you're using Genymotion you can toggle the menu by pressing `CMD + m`, but you may have to enable it in the menu by doing this.

[image]
[image]

- Untick **widget**
- Enable it by `CMD + m` click on **debug in chrome**

Comment: Finally found an Android solution, thanks! And in latest version, the `debug in chrome` is replaced with `start debug remotely`.

Comment: @MewX Could you please let us know how to do that ? 

Comment: @Muhammed Hi, you could just follow `cmd + m` or `ctrl + m`, and select `start debug remotely` from the popup windows in your simulator

Answer (score 55):

if you want to debug using android device on Windows just open a command prompt then type ( make sure your adb working properly)

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

it will prompt a screen like the image 
[image]

then select

```
debug JS Remotely
```

it will automatically open a new window.then open inspect element or press F12 for console.

Comment: is there an iOS equivalent to this command? I just started recently with RN and this would help a lot in the future

Answer (score 38):

<kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> oddly didn't work for me.  Pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd ⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> in the iOS simulator did kick off the debugging browser window for me.

This is the screen that pops up:

[image: React Native debugging options]

[More details here.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#content)

Comment: I don't see these options... :(

Comment: yes in latest works your command works for me

Answer (score 37):

In addition to the other answers. You can debug react-native using the debugger statement

example:

```
debugger; //breaks execution
```

Your chrome dev tools must be open for this to work

Comment: F ya! That's what I needed! Thanks friend!

Answer (score 31):

[image]

Try this program: https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger

Works on: `windows`, `osx` and `linux`.

It supports: `react native` and `redux`

You can also inspect the virtual component tree and modify styles that are reflected in the app.

Comment: Can I view value of specific variable via this debugger? I have tried `console.log(url)`, but I cannot find where output is.

Answer (score 19):

Debugging react-native 0.40.0 on Debian 8 (Jessie) can be done by navigating to [http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6390#issuecomment-236678286) in Chromium or Firebug while your app is running in the android simulator. To access the in-app developer menu, run the following command in another terminal window, as pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40990431):

`adb shell input keyevent 82`

Comment: You can also do this by pressing `D` in your terminal running Metro.

Answer (score 18):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on the previous answers which are great. :)
Here are some of the ways how I am debugging when developing react-native app.

1. **Live reloading**

   react-native makes it super easy to see your changes with the ⌘ + R keys or even just *enable live reload* and watchman will "refresh" the simulator with the latest changes. If you get an error, you can get a clue from the line number from that red screen. A couple of undo will get you back to working state and start again.
2. **`console.log('yeah, seriously.')`**

   I find myself prefer letting the program run and logging some informations than adding a `debugger` break point. (tough debugger is useful when trying to work with external packages/libraries and it comes with autocompletion, so you know what other methods you can utilise.)
3. **`Enable Chrome Debugging`** with **`debugger;`** break point in your program.

Well it depends on the type of errors you encountered and your preferences of how to debug. For most of the `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'something.something')`, method 1 and 2 will be good enough for me.

Whereas dealing with external libraries or packages written by other developers will require more effort to debug hence a good tool like `Chrome Debugging`

Sometimes it is coming from the react-native platform itself so googling for react-native issues will definitely helps.

hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 17):

### React Native 0.62 Released - The **Official** solution is Flipper

[Flipper](https://github.com/facebook/flipper) is Android & iOS Mobile debugging tools without using debug mode in react native.

Since RN 0.62 (See this [link](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2020/03/26/version-0.62)), **Flipper** is initialized with default project.

Flipper has a few of plugins for debugging. The plugins include `Layout`, `Network`, `Shared preferences`

The greatest benefit of Flipper is not also many plugins but you can see Android / iOS device console debugging easily too.

The Flipper alert you about crash or network rejection too.

[image]

Layout plugin includes accessibility mode and target mode.

[image]

You can also see raw network request / response in your Application.

Comment: Do we have to manually install Flipper? Or is it shipped with React Native somehow? If so, how do we open it?

Comment: @Charanor I installed using react native upgrade guide when upgrading to 0.62

Answer (score 16):

Instead of <kbd>Cmd+M</kbd>, for Android Emulator Press <kbd>F10</kbd> in Windows. The emulator starts to show all the react-native debug options.

[image]

Comment: `F10` not working in case of physical device

Answer (score 14):

For Android: Ctrl + M (emulator) or Shake the phone (In Device) to reveal menu.

For iOS: Cmd + D or Shake the Phone to reveal menu

Make sure you have chrome.

On the revealed menu select Debug JS Remotely Option.

Chrome will be opened automatically at localhost:8081/debugger-ui. You can also manually go to debugger with this link.

There reveal console and you can see logs being noted.

Answer (score 12):

```
adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V
```

run this in terminal for android log.

Comment: osx: adb logcat '*:S' ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V

Comment: adb logcat -s ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Microsoft Visual Code , then install React Native Tools extension. Then you can add break points simply by clicking on the desired line number.
Follow these steps to setup and debug app :
[image: SETUP]
[image: RUN]

Dont forget to enable Debug JS Remotely in emulator if you using it.

Answer (score 9):

To me the best way to debug on React-Native is by using ["Reactotron"](https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron).

Install Reactotron then add these to your package.json:

```
"reactotron-apisauce": "^1.1.2",
"reactotron-react-native-under-37": "^1.1.2",
"reactotron-redux": "^1.1.2",
```

now, it just the matter of logging in your code.
e.g.: `console.tron.log('debug')`

Answer (score 9):

1. Run your app in simulator - react-native run-ios
2. Press ctrl + d and click on Debug JS Remotely

[image]

1. webpage should open up at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui , if not type the URL and go to this link in Chrome
2. Right click on the page and click Inspect and it should open the developer tools for chrome

[image]

3. Go to the sources in the top menu and find your js class file in the right hand side file explorer
4. You can put breakpoints to the view and debug the code in there as you can see in the image.

Answer (score 9):

First in your ios simulator, if you press [command + D] key then you can see this screen.

[image]

Then click Debug JS remotely button.

After you might see React Native Debugger page like this.

[image]

And then open your inspector[f12], and go to console tab debug it! :)

Answer (score 7):

If you want to enable debugging by default:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

if (__DEV__) {
  NativeModules.DevSettings.setIsDebuggingRemotely(true)
}
```

To get this working on Android:

```
npm install --save react-native-devsettings-android
react-native link react-native-devsettings-android
```

Reference: [Launch a React Native app with “Debug JS Remotely” enabled by default](https://www.bram.us/2017/12/23/launch-a-react-native-app-with-debug-js-remotely-enabled-by-default/)

Comment: In specific place I should put those 4 lines?   In App.js or index.js?

Comment: @JulienLamarche Put in App.js

Comment: that should be accepted as answer .... why too believe in commands .....

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

By default, my ios simulator wasn't picking up the keystrokes which is why cmd-D didn't work. I had to turn on the settings for the keyboard using simulator's menu:

Hardware > Keyboard > Connect Keyboard

Now cmd-D launches chrome debugging.

Answer (score 6):

For android app .Press Ctrl+M select  debug js remotely it will open a new window in chrome with url http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui. You can now debug the app in chrome browser

Answer (score 5):

Having a space in the file path **prevents** the <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> from working. I moved my project to a location without a space and I finally got the Chrome debugger to work. Seems like a [bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/297).

Answer (score 5):

You can use Safari to debug the iOS version of your app without having to enable "Debug JS Remotely", Just follow the following steps:

```
1. Enable Develop menu in Safari: Preferences → Advanced → Select "Show Develop menu in menu bar"
2. Select your app's JSContext: Develop → {Your Simulator} → Automatically Show Web Inspector for JS JSContext
3. Safari's Web Inspector should open which has a Console and a Debugger
```

Answer (score 4):

Very simple just two commands

```
For IOS $ react-native log-ios
For Android $ react-native log-android
```

Comment: this is the way that I do it!

Comment: This is a super great way to see what is going on with your store

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you want to show this menu on **Android emulator**
 [image]

- Then, try `⌘+m` to pop up this dev settings dialog on Android emulator on a Mac.
- If it doesn't show then go to `AVD > (click the pen to edit your emulator configuration) > advanced settings > check the enable keyboard input box`.
  [image]
- And then retry `⌘+m`.
- If it doesn't show still then go to the running emulator settings and on the `Send keyboard shortcuts to` combobox/dropdown then select the `Emulator controls (default)` option.

[image]

- And then retry `⌘+m`.
- *I hope this helps, it worked for me.*

Answer (score 4):

1. If you are using emulator use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> & simulator <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
2. Click on the - Debug js remotely
3. Google Chrome  go to console

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Redux, I highly recommend React Native Debugger. It includes Chrome devtools, but also has Redux devtools and React devtools.

**Redux Devtools**: This allows you to view your actions, and step back and forth through them. It also allows you to view your redux store and has a feature to automatically diff the previous state with the updated state for each action, so you can see that as you step back and forth through a series of actions.

**React Devtools**: This allows you to inspect a certain component, namely all of it's props as well as it's component state. If you have a piece of the component state which is a boolean, it lets you click it to toggle it and see how your app reacts when it changes. Great feature.

**Chrome Devtools** Allows you to see all your console outputs, use breakpoints, pause on debugger; etc. Standard debugging features. If you right click the area where your actions are listed in Redux Devtools and select 'Allow Network Inspect', you can then inspect your API calls in the network tab of Chrome Devtools which is sweet.

In conclusion having these all in one place is fantastic! If you don't need one of them you can toggle it on/off. Get React Native Debugger and enjoy life.

Answer (score 4):

In React-Native debugging is much easier.

- To debug in IOS use

> cmd + d
>
> ctrl + cmd + z **( For simulator )**

- To debug in android

> Shake device with touch **( Make sure your developer option is enable )**

Comment: Nice explanation.

Answer (score 4):

This is the alternate way to use react native debugger application.

you can download application using below link it's very good application for managing redux store along with the source code.

[react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger)

as well now a days you may directly use below link for help you out.

[chrome-developer-tools](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#chrome-developer-tools)

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1:**
Place `debugger` where ever you want to stop script, like:

```
  async saveItem(item, selectedValue) {
    debugger
    try {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(item, selectedValue);
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.error('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
}
```

This will pause the debugger when ever control comes to this block of code.

**Step 2:**
Press `Cmd+D` on **ios emulator** and `Cmd+M` on **Android simulator**.
If you are having real device, shake the device to open dev menu, if you don't want to shake device follow [this blog](https://medium.com/delivery-com-engineering/react-native-stop-shaking-your-phone-1f4863140146)

**Step 3:**
Select `Enable Remote JS Debugging`, this will open Chrome

[image]

**Step 4:**
Select `Developer Tools.`

[image]

**Step 5:**
Your debugger is paused in `Sources` tab wherever you have written `debugger` within your code . Go to console and type any parameters you want to debug (that are present in the code block) like:
[image]
To move to next debugger point again move to Sources -> click on Resume script execution button (Right corner blue button)

Place the debugger, wherever you wanna pause the script.

Enjoy debugging!!

Answer (score 2):

There is also a very good debuger name Reactotron.
https://github.com/infinitered/reactotron

You don't have to be in debug mode to see some data value and there is a lot of option.

go have a look that is really usefull. ;)

Comment: Thank you! We were using RN 0.59 which didn't seem to be compatible with Flipper.

Answer (score 2):

**Best way to debug react native android and ios app using visual code studio**

**Step 1.**

Install **React Native - Full Pack** extension

**Step 2.**

Connect mobile device using **USB debugging mode** or open emulator from the android studio.

**Step 3.**

Click on debugging option from the left menu in visual code studio 
Click on **Add configuration** and select **React Native** then create **launch.json**

**Step 4.**

Open dev option in the phone on the long back press or shake the phone and Enable **Debug js remotely**

**Step 5.**

Final step click on play button and select **Debug android** or **Debug ios**

For more information refer this link

https://medium.com/@tunvirrahmantusher/android-debug-with-vscode-for-react-native-96f54d73462a

Comment: Step 4 is not clear to me. I understand we need to do that with our app right? My app has some issue that closes the app when I run it on my phone.

Comment: I cannot activate any log yet with that issue

Comment: Leaving default functions on `index` I can see this: https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/NUYTgl6Fgi6978eL8DehOSSQdO5SFqu1/Screenshot_20190415-103126_dejaVu.png

Comment: your react redux is not properly installed remove node_module and install npm again

Comment: It was related to some deprecated library I had to install manually. Thanks for pointing

Answer (score 1):

It's actually pretty simple. Just press cmd D (if on mac) and the simulator will create a pop up menu. From there just click "Debug JS Remotely" or something along the lines of that. Beware that running the debugger while executing code related to certain packages has been known to give people problems. I had a problem with react-native-maps and the debugger. But that was fixed. For the most part you should be fine though.

Answer (score 1):

to debug your react native app just go to the following address:

**localhost:8081/debugger-ui**
in your default browser(chrome) and open developer tools to debug your react native app

Comment: Thank you. I can see a page showing some message and instructions as you answered. How to debug the code is not mentioned anywhere, where I can see my code.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Nuclide in Atom editor for React Native App Development then you can also "Element Inspector" which helps in observing props and state values changes when app is running on device in development phase.

Know more about it [here](https://nuclide.io/docs/platforms/react-native/#element-inspector)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. run in terminal `adb logcat *:S ReactNative:V ReactNativeJS:V`
2. open project in Android Studio, open `logcat` (button on the bottom panel)
3. run in terminal `react-native run-android`

After building, you should see detail logs in Android Studio in `logcat`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use custom lib for that if you don't want to shake your real phone every 2 minutes

I've created a lib that allows you to **use 3 fingers touch instead of shake** to open dev menu, when in development mode

https://github.com/pie6k/react-native-dev-menu-on-touch

You only have to wrap your app inside:

import DevMenuOnTouch from 'react-native-dev-menu-on-touch';
// or:  import { DevMenuOnTouch } from 'react-native-dev-menu-on-touch'

```
class YourRootApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <DevMenuOnTouch>
        <YourApp />
      </DevMenuOnTouch>
    );
  }
}
```

It's really useful when you have to debug on real device and you have co-workers sitting next to you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Flipper](https://fbflipper.com/) or [reactotron](http://%20infinitered/reactotron:%20A%20desktop%20app%20for%20inspecting%20...%20-%20GitHubhttps://github.com%20%E2%80%BA%20infinitered%20%E2%80%BA%20reactotron). each one has its own benefits and none requires you to enable debug mode, so your environment won't get slow!

Answer (score 1):

On the simulator pressing `Cmd+D` and selecting **Debug** will open the browser Debugger

Answer (score 1):

To activate Debugger in React Native cli do the following:

The metro will start running after,

```
~ npm start
```

To run project in Emulator or Device

```
~ npx react-native run-android
```

To start the Debugger,

```
~ adb shell input keyevent 82     //debugger command or shake the device to alternate to this command
```

after press debug which appears in emulator or device to start debugger then,

```
~ npx react-native run-android     //to run the app because adb need this command to start debugger in browser
```

To Deactivate Debugger:-

```
~ adb shell input keyevent 82     //debugger command or shake the device to alternate to this command
```

after press Stop debug which appears in emulator or device to stop debugger.

Comment: Or you can log through your vscode where you typed npm start. After executing the app the vscode debugger will console the errors and logs there by default when chrome debugger is not started.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows and using the android emulator you can do this steps:

1. After the emulator is running and the app on it, press the **Menu** button and then select "Debug JS Remotely" or "Debug in Chrome" (It depends the emulator using). You can see the next image as reference: [emulator with steps image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yNou.png)
2. A new Chrome Tab will appears. You must press Ctrl + ⇧J to show the Developer tools and start tracking the debug steps. [See this image as reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnUkF.png)

Additionally you should us the `console.log()` feature to make the debugging process more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

You can install React Native Debugger from brew. it's more comfortable to use than debugger in chrome

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what I am doing. If I am making UI changes or debugging UI, I typically turn on live and hot reloading and make changes then get instant feedback on it. If it's something more technical, I turn on JS debugging to look at the state of the app. However because reloading is so quick in react native, if the state is too messy, I just console log.

Answer (score 0):

If you run your app on real devices, which is connected to the laptop, you can debug it via terminal using `react-native log-ios` or `react-native log-android` (It works also for simulators)

Answer (score 0):

You can use expo for debugging: https://expo.io/

> Expo lets web developers build truly native apps that work across both
>   iOS and Android by writing them once in just JavaScript. It's open
>   source, free and uses React Native.

This is a great tool and you can watch this workshop at React Europe conf:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HygXkQDMSGU&t=6675s

Answer (score 0):

A technique that I use that very similar to a debugging tactic in Android is to include a global variable called TAG in all my .js files.

```
const TAG = 'APP_NAME+SCREEN_NAME';
```

Then where needed, I'll do: `console.log(TAG + 'ACTION');`

This way, I can track actions and see where the log statements are coming from.

Answer (score 0):

In new version of react-native you can use `react-native log-android` or  `react-native log-android` to see logs of your application in dev mode.

Comment: You probably meant `react-native log-ios`

Answer (score 0):

I use this library to debug react-native projects

https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger
It includes

1. Includes React Inspector from react-devtools-core.
2. Includes Redux
   DevTools, made the same API with redux-devtools-extension.

or you can use

```
For IOS $ react-native log-ios
For Android $ react-native log-android
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native Debugger. It's helps me to solve 90% of my problems

Answer (score 0):

if you want know about inspect network traffic and understand the native UI view hierarchy. With its extensible plugin API then React Native Update version provide developer tool for debugging mobile apps.

Flipper is a great developer tool for debugging mobile apps. This tool is shipped with react-native 62

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Run your application in the Android simulator.
    2. Press Ctrl + D and a webpage should open up at http://localhost:8081/debugger-ui. (Chrome only for now)
    3. Enable Pause On Caught Exceptions for a better debugging experience.
    4. Press F12 to open the Chrome Developer tools, or open it via View -> Developer -> Developer Tools.
```