# How to disable start of Parallels when script interacts with "Google Chrome"

Tags: macos, google-chrome, parallels

When I have automation against Google Chrome on OSX, for example from AppleScript, OSX start Windows 8 in Parallels to start Chrome there, I just want OSX to interact with the OSX version of Google Chrome!

Any idea how to disable this, or let OSX first interact with the OSX version of Google Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer! In *Virtual Machine settings > Options* disable the option  *Share Windows applications with Mac*.[image]