# Can I step by step debug the react-native js code?

Tags: react-native

Can I step by step debug the react-native js code?

Otherwise, how can i debug my code to find out the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you debug react-native?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)

Answer (score 2):

First, you define the  `debugger`whenever you feel this get me an error.

[image: you can see my code whenever my on press event is triggered then i have put that debuggger.]

then open in simulator or device developer menu and press `debug with chrome` this will be very useful to step by step debugging.

then inspect the code and go to the source tab.

you can see the down step and up step arrow, using that you can debug step by step.