# React Native : In-app developer menu android (genymotion)

Tags: android, react-native, genymotion

I unable to access the In-App Developer Menu in android(genymotion). Everytime I press the home button, it's not showing the developer menu, and it shift my UI a bit lower which I can't revert it back, unless I kill the app and restart it again. Yes I did check in android module, it is in debug mode.

Answer (score 7):

I usually do the following:

```
adb shell input keyevent 82
```

Actually, I defined an alias for it in my `.(bash|zsh)rc`:

```
alias shake='adb shell input keyevent 82'
```

Comment: where is .(bash|zsh)rc exactly? i tried the first option. not working though.

Comment: I meant it as either the `.zshrc` or the  `.bashrc`, depends on which shell you are using. The are located in your home directory.

Answer (score 3):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (or <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> if you are running on a Mac) to invoke the In-App Developer Menu.

Comment: did that already. but nothing is showing and its endup shifting my UI abit lower. I also tried to run the app on a physical device, still the same. the developer menu not showing anything

Comment: @thundeNilla Can you provide a screenshot on the issue?

Comment: the problem is, its not showing anything. Even in the console RN and logcat android. its just not triggering anything.