# React Native: How to debug

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get better debugging with React Native using `react-devtools`

```
npm install -g react-devtools && react-devtools*
```

But it always show connecting...
It doesn't work

Comment: Please give more details of the steps you have tried so far. Also: Do react-devtools work in conjunction with a browser extension that you do not have installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you debug react-native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)

Comment: 1、 in terminal， react-native run-ios
2、 command + d  open Debug JS Remotely
3、 in project root directory, in terminal ， react-devtools

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug an attached device:

Make sure the device is connected via adb

```
adb devices
```

Ensure adb reverse is enabled for port 8097

```
adb reverse tcp:8097 tcp:8097
react-devtools
```

I've found the following 2 pages very useful:

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device

Answer (score 0):

Under the `scripts` section in your package.json, add the following:

> "debug": "react-devtools"

Then run `npm run debug` from your project directory. Your app should now connect.

You can also look into [React Native Debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger) which is a bit easier to use (in my opinion).

Comment: it doesn't work , maybe my steps are wrong？ 
1、 react-native run-ios
2、 open Debug JS Remotely
3、 npm run debug