# React Native Dev Menu not Appearing

Tags: debugging, react-native

I'm debugging a React Native app in the AVD Android Emulator running a Nexus 5X API 27 Oreo on Windows 10, and the developer menu will not show using the steps mentioned in this StackOverflow question [How do you debug React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)

1. Using `Ctrl + M` on the emulator enables the multi-gesture action instead of the dev menu. `Windows + M` minimizes all open windows. I have also tried going into `Settings > Send keyboard shortcuts to > Virtual device`.
2. Using the `adb shell input keyevent 82` command does not do anything. I tried going into `adb shell` and running the command `input keyevent 82`.
3. Shaking the device using `Virtual Sensors > Accelerometer` does not bring up the menu by shaking the device.
4. Upgraded from API 27 Oreo to API 28 Pie.

So far I was able to open the Dev Menu using Step 2, but it stopped working all of a sudden, without any changes to the React Native code as far as I know. I tried running it on a physical device and shaking it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

For me this happened when I connected a real device at the same time as the simulator was running.
After real device was disconnected and app was rebuilt Cmd+M (Mac OS) worked again.