# Lerna, React-Redux Web Application debug using Visual code editor debugger for Chrome plugin

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, google-chrome-devtools, lerna

I am currently working on Lerna React-Redux project, where multiple packages like one MainApp, and other packages like header, products, cart, shared-components etc.
I am using Visual code editor and Chrome debug tool, for debugging when I set a breakpoint and try to debug continuously line by line it's open bundle.js file for distributed packages like product to card package or any others. Is there any source map option in webpack config file.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, the problem is resolved by changing the value of Devtool source-map to eval-source-map on web pack configuration file, more details information I found web pack official documentation https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#development

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctr+M on emulator and choose Debug remote. this will directly open a developer window on chrome browser.

You will find following link useful
[How do you debug React Native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)

Comment: The application is only for Web-Based, no react native has been used. simple react 16 and  redux, Lerna 2.10.1