# How to debug react-native in Visual Studio Code

Tags: react-native

I am trying to understand and debug existing react-native code for mobile app. I am using Visual Studio as editor. I am building the app in mobile and not using simulator for building the app. I am using console.log() statements for logging the values/responses. After/During I build the app, I do not see any log printed in the terminal. How do I print the console statement in VS code for react-native app?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for [this](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html#debugging-on-a-device-with-chrome-developer-tools)

The setup is different for iOS and android, but this will allow you to connect to the chrome dev tools via USB and see the `console.log` statements in the browser console.

On iOS:

> Find and edit RCTWebSocketExecutor.m, change the value of "localhost" to your computers IP address

and android:

> run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Then you can open the dev menu on your app (by shaking your phone) and select "Debug JS remotely"

Alternatively, you can use `console.warn` instead of `console.log`, since `console.warn` triggers a `YellowBox` error that will be visible while running the app on your phone in debug mode.

Comment: I tried running this command ( adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 ) in terminal, it says command not found. Also, I am new to react and new to app-development, so if there is something else needs to done to run that command then please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: I also tried using, console.warn instead of console.log, nothing showed up anywhere.

Comment: hm are you using `Expo` by chance? if so you should look here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/debugging if you don't have `adb` installed then you are most likely using `Expo`. If you don't have `adb` installed and you are not using `Expo` then you need to go through the `apps with native code` setup process

Answer (score 0):

1. Run app in mobile using  'react-native run-ios --device'
2. Shake your device, this will open a action sheet menu like :-[image]
3. Click debug JS Remotely this will open url like  :8081/debugger-ui/  in your browser.
4. right click on that page and select inspect menu.
5. now select console tab and here your log will be displayed like [image]