# Developer Menu have not `Debug JS Remotely`?

Tags: react-native

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmU6z.png)

initialization:

```sh
npm install -g react-native-cli

react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject
react-native run-android
```

open `Developer Menu`

```
./adb.exe shell input keyevent 82
```

Developer Menu have not `Debug JS Remotely` and `Enable Live Reload` ?

https://react-native.org/doc/debugging.html

Comment: how are you connecting the device?via Wifi?

Comment: Android simulator

Answer (score 0):

I hope this SO thread helps you, feel free to ask any doubts :

[Debug in simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29289304/how-do-you-debug-react-native)