# ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property 'animationInterpolators' of undefined

Tags: react-native

I use the `resetTo` method of `Navigator`. After the render the reset page, i got the error. How to fix the problem.

```
ExceptionsManager.js:61 Cannot read property 'animationInterpolators' of undefined
handleException @ ExceptionsManager.js:61
handleError @ InitializeJavaScriptAppEngine.js:89
ErrorUtils.reportFatalError @ error-guard.js:27
guard @ MessageQueue.js:44
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue @ MessageQueue.js:87
onmessage @ debuggerWorker.js:39
```

Answer (score 1):

The stack trace isn't very helpful here because it's just React Native error handling code. Ideally it would print out the real stack trace, but it looks like you can find out the real error using the Chrome debugger. If you're not already doing so, enable "Debug in Chrome" from the dev options menu. The Chrome page has instructions for enabling [Pause on Caught Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors/17324511#17324511), which will pause the debugger at a better place so you can debug it further.

That answers what to do if you see a stack trace with `ExceptionsManager.js`, but I don't know about your specific error. If you're still stuck, you might try editing your question to include the relevant code and better stack trace that you get from the Chrome debugger.