# .bind TypeErrors after updating to Angular 1.5.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I updated a project from Angular 1.3.5 to 1.5.8 and now I'm getting errors on view elements that have `data-ui-mask="...."`. I'm also getting .bind errors in a service that was created to handle scrolling functionality.

I did upgrade all dependencies in my `bower.json` to ensure everything is up-to-date.

Here is one of the error messages:

```
TypeError: r.bind is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:32:10980)
at https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:810
at me (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:7:1828)
at f (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:26481)
at a (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:22545)
at a (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:22562)
at a (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:22562)
at a (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:22562)
at f (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:26425)
at a (https://localhost:3000/assets/vendor-0.0.7.min.js:6:22545) <input type="text" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="AGENT_SSN" data-ng-model="agentModel.query.advanced.AGENT_SSN" data-ui-mask="999-99-9999">
```

Here is an example of the code causing one of the errors: (note: I have about 5 of these elements using `data-ui-mask=""` and all of them throw errors)

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="AGENT_SSN" data-ng-model="agentModel.query.advanced.AGENT_SSN" data-ui-mask="999-99-9999">
```

Here is the ScrollService that is also throwing a .bind TypeError:

```
agency.factory('ScrollService', [function() {
    var module = angular.element(document.getElementById('scrollable-div'));
    var scroll = function(elementId) {
        var scrollTo = angular.element(document.getElementById(elementId));
        module.scrollToElement(scrollTo, 40, 500);
    };
    return scroll;
}]);
```

This project worked with Angular 1.3.5 and I changed nothing with the code. All dependencies are being injected. I'm guessing it's a jQuery issue, but I can't confirm it.

*** UPDATE ***

In my `gulpfile.js` I pointed to the non-minified jquery and all the errors went away. I want to use minified file, so now I'll look into why this would happen. Is this an error with jQuery??

Comment: Which version of `ui-mask` are you using?

Comment: Version: 1.8.7 - This should the latest and greatest.

Comment: Also did you make sure some of the dependencies aren't being installed from old cache? Had this issue today.

Comment: I went through and did a `bower uninstall --save package` on every dependency, hopefully that was enough.

Comment: Not sure what was your intention with that. But it doesn't stop local cache from being used. What I would recommend is remove bower_components and reinstall using `bower install --force`. This will ensure everything is resolved using remote repos, not local cache.

Comment: I'll give it a try.

Comment: Another thing I'd suggest is try to debug with non-minified code. Angular error call stack us usually useless, but it gets even more useless when called functions are named `r`, `f` and `a` :)

Comment: Just tried `bower install --force` and I still get the errors. I'll work with the non-minified code to see if I can get any more clues.

Comment: You might also try enabling pause on error in chrome: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors. This will put you in context of erroneous code and might give you an idea of what's happening. Sorry for being an useless smartass, but I have no clue why this error is happening, just trying to give some suggestions that might help you debug faster.

Comment: I've been working on this for half the day and I'm out of ideas, so your help is greatly appreciated.