# Too much recursion in angular.js regarding equals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

I'm working on a angular.js webapplication and I experience a too much recursion error. the error listed below appears several times (2 times every second) in succession immediately in the console during the failure.

Because the log statements locate the errors only in angular.js script, I don't know where to look for the error in my own code. Are there in general some frequently code snippets/ constructs which could cause the error below?

Unfortunately due to the size of the webapp and because I don't know where to look for the cause, it is hard to provide a MWE.

Console from Chrome

```
RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at equals (angular.js:1078)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1088)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1088)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1104)
    at equals (angular.js:1088)
(anonymous) @ angular.js:13920
(anonymous) @ angular.js:10467
$digest @ angular.js:17542
$apply @ angular.js:17790
(anonymous) @ angular.js:19621
completeOutstandingRequest @ angular.js:5964
(anonymous) @ angular.js:6243
```

Console from Firefox

```
   Error: too much recursion
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1102:1
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1104:14
    equals@http://0.0.0.0:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1088:16
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: Is there a way to get Chrome to break on all errors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors)

Comment: between you and us, you have a lot better chance to locate the issue in your code because we don't have your code

Comment: @JaromandaX therefore I asked for general code fragments which can cause a too much recursion error in angular.js equals

Comment: Asking for an off-site resource is beyond the scope of Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @d4rty - sorry, didn't see that part in the middle of the question :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you have some self-referential objects that you are testing for equality.  Set a breakpoint at `angular.js:1104` and then walk up the stack to see what these objects are.