# javascript trying to display undefined variable error

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to show all JS errors? by all errors I mean fore example undefined variable (without using try & catch in every function - which is painless)

Comment: use TypeScript you will be amazed

Comment: Using try+catch is not appropriate unless the exception is to be "meaningfully handled" (which should mean something more relevant than "written to the console"). In any case, if using the *developer tools* in Chrome you can enable 'break on every exception'. The introduction of the unexpected value is the original flaw and such remnants should be cleared through integration tests (using the browser / engine to help fix tests) and fixed before release.

Comment: @Haris yes, I know, but for that project I can't use typescript:(

Comment: @user2864740 try + catch for every function will be painfull:(. Where in Chrome is 'break on every exception' option?:)

Comment: @K.A.T. Ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors