# React Native run-android error in emulator "Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

I am using Android Studio Emulator and configured `react-native-web` support as per [this doc](https://dev.to/shivams136/create-react-native-app-for-android-ios-and-web-without-expo-48lc) as well. But Whenever I run `npm run android` it gets the below error:

[image: Error Screenshot]

**"Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly"**

I tried many solutions out there like:

- Delete `node_modules` and re install
- Clear cache in `react-native start --reset-cache`
- Run `react-native start` before `run-android`
- check `.npmrc`

But no solution yet. There is no error in `metro` terminal as well.

Below is my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "shipdemo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start --reset-cache",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "web": "webpack serve -d source-map --mode development --config \"./web/webpack.config.js\" --inline --color --hot",
    "build:web": "webpack --mode production --config \"./web/webpack.config.js\" --hot"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-web": "^0.16.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-native-web": "^0.16.5",
    "eslint": "7.14.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native-web"
  }
}
```

---

#### UPDATE:

After enabling [Pause on Caught Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2233339/javascript-is-there-a-way-to-get-chrome-to-break-on-all-errors/17324511#17324511), I got below in the dev tools.

[image]

At the same time, Now I got an error in metro as well
[image]

Comment: I followed that same tutorial too, and now get the same error. I'm suspecting that the Babel configuration that aliased `react-native` to `react-native-web` is taking effect in normal `react-native start`. Because it was just working fine before `react-native-web`. I'm gonna play with it and let you know.

Comment: I was not able to fix it, but I deleted the emulator device from AVD and created a new device with Play Store API, API 29 and now everything is working fine. I have not posted it here yet as this should not be the only solution. Also, I moved the `.babelrc` config to `webpack.config.js`

Comment: My code was working fine, but suddenly this error began to occur and then I couldn't solve it, So I performed the above steps and it was resolved, but I don't know "how".

Comment: I tested many things, but I think I found the culprit. Playing with the babel and flow configs is provoking that error. Whenever I remove the added values on those configs, and launch with `--reset-cache` it works great. I can't provide an answer yet, because there seem to be a bug too in version 0.64 connected with RN. But I tried removing config from babel and flow for React Native Web, and only keep alias in webpack config, and the web builds normally and works great, native App works great too that way.

Comment: In React Native Web documentation, they provide ways to integrate config with Webpack, Babel and Flow. But they never specify that you had to add them all. So at some points, may be webpack alias does not bother normal React Native, while Babel and/or Flow break the bundle for native App. If we could instead specify our own babel and flow config under web directory along with webpack (if they are really necessary), normal RN configs would remain untouched.

Comment: I can confirm that I don't need any config modification at all outside of webpack when using React-Native-Web. Just setting the presets and plugins direction in webpack `use.options` is enough, so that you don't need them in babel config. I also made it works with NextJS also, with simple webpack overriding in `next.config.js`. This way I can handle lighter multipage website with 90% same React-Native codes.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I'll update the article. But is this the source of error also?

Comment: Yes, I think so, because I never had the error on native again. And I tested it with NextJS also, I only keep the babel react native presets in babel config, that's all. I have the feeling some configs are for like if you import views from react-native or react-native-web in your components, but I don't understand all those configs well enough to know all details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the fix but the reason behind it, posting this answer for increasing the visibility of the solution which is equivalent to [this commit](https://github.com/ShivamS136/react-native-web-setup/commit/c73b8c4139f0b86fc3d1734f1bc8a7014d00e24b).

So I removed `.babelrc` file and moved the module resolver settings to the webpack config, updated `babel.config.js` so now the web related settings will not disturb the App-related babel settings.

I have updated [the mentioned article](https://dev.to/shivams136/create-react-native-app-for-android-ios-and-web-without-expo-48lc) as well.

---

**`.babelrc`:**

<Deleted>

**`babel.config.js`:**

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
};
```

**`web/webpack.config.js`:**

```js
...
...
...

      // The 'metro-react-native-babel-preset' preset is recommended to match React Native's packager
      presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
      // Re-write paths to import only the modules needed by the app
      plugins: [
        'react-native-web',
        [
          'module-resolver',
          {
            alias: {
              '^react-native$': 'react-native-web',
            },
          },
        ],
      ],
...
...
...
```

Answer (score 0):

restart your Metro Bundler

```
  yarn start --reset-cache
```